# How to dynamically load apps like Expo client

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

Is it possible to load "sub-apps" inside a mobile application? The way like [Expo client](https://expo.io/tools#client) does that - you start a "parent" app and inside that you dynamically load other apps.

**Requirements:**

- Parent app downloadable from the store.
- Sub-apps not published in the store
- Sub-apps always up to date - possibility to update them independently on the parent app.
- Android and iOS compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remotely deploy with CodePush.
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/rn-overview.

The limitation is the same as Expo's, in that you can only push JS code.
Anything that runs on the native side would require a new build and App Store / Google Play Store release.

Other than that, you can always resort to running stuff in a WebView.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't know about the Expo's OTA updates. That's what I was looking for. Thank you for pointing me the right direction.